# "Trap" control-d and control-c

Tags: c++

I have a console program and I want if the user press ctrl-z the program exits and if he press ctrl-c nothing happens. In Bash i'd put a trap, what I should use in C++?

Comment: Does your console program have a more elaborate UI than the usual stdin/stdout processor? What kind is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Unix use `signal()` in `<signal.h>` to register a function to invoke upon receiving a signal.

For example:

```
#include <signal.h>

void leave(int sig);

// ...
{
    signal(SIGINT,leave);
    for(;;) getchar();
}

// Beware:  calling library fn from signal handler isn't std-conforming
//          and may not work.
void leave(int sig)
{
    exit(sig);
}
```

Comment: You should be calling `_Exit(sig)` instead of `exit(sig)` here. The former is safe within signal handlers the latter is not.

Comment: `signal()` behaves differently on different platforms. `sigaction()` is slightly more complicated, but is portable.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a UNIX based system, then you want either [`signal()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signal.html) or [`sigaction()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) depending on your preference and threading model; personally, I would recommend `sigaction()` over `signal()`.  You want to trap `SIGTSTP` and `SIGINT`.  Read [the *Signal Concepts* section of the Single UNIX Specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) for a good description of how to use them.

If you have some spare time, read the W. Richard Steven's classic [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/).  You will never be sorry.  If you expect to be doing more UNIX system's programming tasks, then pick up copies of [POSIX Programmers Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0937175730) and [POSIX.4 Programmers Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565920740) as well.  They serve as great introductions and references.

Answer (score 2):

For the Ctrl + C you have to catch SIGINT signal. [Look here.](http://users.evtek.fi/~tk/rtp/signals-programming.html#catching)

Answer (score 1):

That's platform specific, of course. C++ itself has no knowledge of keyboard input or signal handling.

As you mentioned bash, I guess you are on Linux or some kind of UN*X. In this case, take a look at [signal.h](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/signal.h.html).

Comment: The C and C++ standards both have a lot to say about signal handling and keyboard input. Neither have much to say about process suspension though but `SIGINT` and `signal()` are both covered.

Comment: I don't think the C or C++ language assumed that there even is a keyboard. But you're right, both `SIGINT` and `signal()` are part of the C standard header `signal.h`, meaning you can set signal handling functions and raise signals.